# Vagrant up stucks at "SSH auth method: private key"

Tags: networking, ssh, ansible, vagrant, backend

I am using virtual box on my mac machine. I am trying to work with vagrant and ansible. While running **vagrant up** command, process stucks at **"default: SSH auth method: private key"**

Here is my vagrantfile

```
PROJECT_NAME = "petalandstem"
BACKEND_DIR = "/home/vagrant/#{PROJECT_NAME}/src/backend"
FRONTEND_DIR = "/home/vagrant/#{PROJECT_NAME}/src/frontend"

Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.8.1"
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.hostname = PROJECT_NAME
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

#  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.0.23"
#  config.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.50.4"
  config.vm.network "public_network", ip:"192.168.0.23"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  #config.ssh.port = "22"
  #config.ssh.host = '192.168.22.22'
  config.vm.synced_folder "./backend", BACKEND_DIR
  config.vm.synced_folder "./frontend", FRONTEND_DIR

# config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000, auto_correct: true
# config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 2222, host: 22  
# config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080,auto_correct: true
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.name = PROJECT_NAME
    vb.memory = "512"
    vb.cpus = 1
    vb.gui = true
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "ansible/site.yml"
    ansible.inventory_path = "ansible/vagrant.ini"
    ansible.host_key_checking = false
    ansible.limit = "*"
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please avoid posting images for your error messages. This is not at all convenient as the responders have to look at a different page and cannot copy/paste errors for research or other means. Put your error in a code block which is suited for that. Thanks in advance to edit your message and make this change.

Comment: Why are you defining a static `config.ssh.host` address ? Is that address actually configured correctly in your vm ? From what I can see I don't think it is. Moreover, you are redefining `config.ssh.port` to 22 although the forwarded port for NAT is set to 2222 in your run log. Remove those two ssh config lines for now and try again to see if it works.

Comment: @Zeitounator entire system ran correctly, I still have 2 questions

1) I am doing ping at public network but no replies on that

Comment: @Zeitounator entire system runs and gives following message:
==>default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.

If I run vagrant provision, it gives me this error: ansible software not found

Comment: Comments are not to ask new questions. Please create a new question for that.